# Microsoft Team Webhook Integration in C#

Tags: c#, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to develop a custom application that will integrate with Microsoft Teams. I need to fetch metadata (such as name, meeting id, time, etc.) from Microsoft Teams.

Any idea on how I can use webhooks?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that kind of data from a webhook, your better bet is the Microsoft Graph API. The Graph API covers a large part of the Microsoft 365 products, not just Teams, so you need to find the operations you specifically want, but this is a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

In order to work with Graph though, you need to understand a bit about how it works, especially with regards permissions and authorisation. This should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Yes, it is the Microsoft Graph API, thank you for your answer

Comment: Sure thing. If it's been helpful, please upvote or mark it as the answer, so others with a similar question can find it more easily.